# LINQ to perform action for correspning/related items, or databindg technique?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I have a ListBox that I populate from a database view, and then I want to add an attribute to each ListItem.  Imagine if the user can select a City on the page and some javascript runs to filter down the listbox to only employees in that city.  The javascript is no problem, but I need to add an attribute to each listitem that indicates what city the employee belongs to.  Of course I could just have a couple loops where employeeID matches add the City.  **Is there was a better way using databinding or some sort of LINQ query to accomplish this?**

```
employeesListBox.DataSource = (from p in dwEntitiesContext.Employees
                                      orderby p.name
                                      select p).ToList();

      employeesListBox.DataTextField = "Full Name";
      employeesListBox.DataValueField = "EmployeeID";
      employeesListBox.DataBind();

      //this gives you the idea of what I want to do, 
      //but obviously I can't access p.City here
      //Was wondering if there was some technique of doing a join, 
      //or some way to databind the attribute
      employeesListBox.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Select(eachItem => 
      eachItem.Attributes.Add("CityID", p.City 
      /*set City attribute of the employee this listitem represents*/));
```

By adding the CityID attribute, my javascript/jquery will a way to filter the listbox as users select different cities.  Note that I am not asking you to filter the list in advance, because that would require a postback everytime the user selects a City.  I am just giving you this extra info because people often want to know more background than just the task at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like that:

```
foreach(var employee in dwEntitiesContext.Employees.OrderBy(e => e.name))
{
    var listItem = new ListItem
        {
            Text = employee.FullName,
            Value = employee.EmployeeID
        };

    listItem.Attributes.Add("CityID", employee.City);

    employeesListBox.Items.Add(listItem);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, this does away with the databinding, which I've always tried to use databinding because that's what I'm used to.  I know in Win forms applications it has alot of benefits.  I've never actually found it to be very helpful in ASP.NET applications though, because your code, beind no longer than my code, seems to accomplish the same thing that databinding does, and makes me wonder why I bother with the databinding.